# href="#" causes location address to change, can we avoid it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a number of tabs that I handle special logic so no location bar address change should occur. I have the following

```
<a href="#">Home</a>
```

This behaves as expected, i.e. it gives me the hand mouse pointer when hovering over the buttons but clicking on then starts the route change. I want to be able to stop this.

I tried just remove the `href` or setting `href=""`, seemed to have some success but it gave unexpected results when hovering.

What is the best practice here? Do I have to remove the href? So then I will need to style the tab using CSS to give me the mouse pointer when hovering? If I do leave the `href="#"` in the link then this causes a change of routing which is not what I was looking for.

I actually handle my login in a `ngClick` for each tab. This logic must not change the route.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Home</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but is this not mixing js with html, i wanted to get away from that... Although if there is no other way ??

Comment: If you want to retain your logic then you need to mix a bit of js with the html. Another option, as you have already mentioned would be to remove the href attribute  and apply the cursor:pointer style to your element.

Comment: Just a heads-up: Angular is a framework that relies heavily on extending HTML syntax, so I don't think you can get away from mixing Javascript (or Angular expressions) with HTML. And I think that's perfectly fine when using that sort of framework. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978507/dont-the-data-attribute-options-used-in-bootstrap-angular-js-and-ember-js-con) provides more insights on that matter.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue. And also agree with Michael here.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use the `<base>` tag, you can simply use:

```xml
<a href="">Home</a>
```

Indeed, according to the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aa):

> [...] the default action is prevented when `href` attribute is empty.

Well, the documentation is wrong, and the real behaviour is actually to prevent the default action when the `href` attribute is equal to page location. That's a problem when you're using `<base>`. In this case, you have two choices:

- Forget the `href` attribute. That works fine, but your page will not be valid anymore, since the `href` attribute is mandatory for a `<a>` tag.
- Create your own directive, for instance `aEmpty`, whose goal is simply to fill the `href` attribute of a real `<a>` with the current value of `$location.path()`.

In all cases, you'd better to actually use CSS to style your link, because that's always a bad idea to rely on the default behaviour of the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `href`  with `ng_click`.

To get the hand mouse pointer, add the css style:

```
a { cursor: pointer ; }
a:hover   { color: #00c }  /* user hovers     */
```