# Prevent page template changing when the link `href='#'` in routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, route-provider

I've been migrating my projects from JQuery to Angular.js

I have several links that targeted to '#', for example in bootstrap dropdown:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">                                 
    Administrator <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li>
      <a id="logout" href="logout.html">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Logout
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I try to implement page routing with angular routeProvider

```
$routeProvider.when('/content/chat', {
  templateUrl: config.indexURL + 'content/chat',
  controller: 'ChatCtrl'
})
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });;
```

The page keep changing when the link targeted to '#' meanwhile I want to keep them not redirected

I've got a solution that we can changes the href attribute to `javascript:void(0);`

[href="#" causes location address to change, can we avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080715/href-causes-location-address-to-change-can-we-avoid-it)

but there are so many links that targeted to # in my pages (many of them generated by JQuery plugins)
and I don't want to change it one by one.

Is there any way to prevent page changing when the link `href='#'` in routeProvider settings?

Answer (score 0):

Wahat you want **is** to allow the page change (the default) behavior when you click on a `#`. You need to rewrite your code for jumping to a part of the page behavior of the old `#`.

For that, you may use Angular's `$anchorScroll`. Here is an example (taken from their site)

```
<div id="scrollArea" ng-controller="ScrollController">
  <a ng-click="gotoBottom()">Go to bottom</a>
  <a id="bottom"></a> You're at the bottom!
</div>
```

And your controller is:

```
angular.module('anchorScrollExample', [])
  .controller('ScrollController', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll',
    function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
      $scope.gotoBottom = function() {
        // set the location.hash to the id of
        // the element you wish to scroll to.
        $location.hash('bottom');

        // call $anchorScroll()
        $anchorScroll();
      };
    }]);
```

Comment: Is there any other way than changing the href='#' to ng-click? Btw, I don't need to scroll down the page. What I realy need is to make the page still on the same place. For example when I click a link href='#', I want to show the bootstrap dropdown.

Comment: There is always a way. But you are talking about fundamentally changing the way angular routing works. As for opening a bootstrap, you should then use ngClick or even better a directive for that. You should stop thinking the JQuery way and start thinking the Angular way